# How to have input fields arranged in HBox/VBox?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table and in one of the column's I am trying to show 4 input fields with 2*2 manner

For eg i have a Sample Column :

I have tried VBox as :

```
                        <Column>
                        <m:Text text="Sample Column" />
                        <template>
                            <m:VBox visible="true">
                                <m:Input value="test1" editable='false'/>
                                <m:Input value="test2" editable='false'/>
                                <m:Input value="test3" editable='false'/>
                                <m:Input value="test4" editable='false'/>
                            </m:VBox>
                        </template>
                    </Column>
```

[image: and the result is as:]

I have tried HBox(replacing VBox above and some random text) and it shows all columns as:

[image: Using HBox]

May i know how to achieve 2*2 as (trying to explain):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<m:VBox visible="true">
    <m:HBox>
        <m:Input value="test1" editable='false'/>
        <m:Input value="test2" editable='false'/>
    </m:HBox>
    <m:HBox>
        <m:Input value="test3" editable='false'/>
        <m:Input value="test4" editable='false'/>
    </m:HBox>
</m:VBox>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the Quick Sol....Is there something like FlexBox and I have tried that i adjusts it self but in this case can i achieve the same with FlexBox ?

Comment: VBox and HBox are FlexBoxes. I think you might want to look into a SimpleForm with a ResponsiveGridLayout.

Comment: In newer sapui5 versions you can leverage also CSS grids: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.cssgrid.CSSGrid